# How to get Mouse support for dtterm terminal in solaris

Tags: terminal, solaris, gnu-screen

When i run vim inside screen, with TERM set to dtterm, there is no mouse support. How do i enable mouse support for dtterm TERMINAL.

Running TERM with xtermc is not feasible as this garbles the background color in vim when running inside screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one problem:

- `xtermc` does not match any terminal that you are likely to encounter (noted in xterm FAQ *[What $TERM should I use?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_terminfo)*
- `dtterm` does not match `xtermc` either (use `infocmp xtermc dtterm` to see).
- Sun stopped providing up-to-date terminal entries about 20 years ago.  Perhaps the *last* change was related to `dtterm`.  At the time, their `/etc/termcap` file had an incorrectly-formatted entry for `dtterm`.
- `dtterm` does *not* support xterm-style mouse functionality.  As I recall it, the mindset of its developers was that no one used it.  So all you can get is GUI-style (non-programmatic) mouse select/paste.
- `dtterm` does attempt to emulate VT220 (which had no mouse), but has some problems in that (a [bug](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#bug_dtterm) in scrolling).
- ncurses has an improved terminal description for `dtterm`, but that bug in scrolling cannot be described in terminfo (other than pretending that `dtterm` cannot scroll).
- `dtterm` was part of CDE, which Sun deprecated as of Solaris 10.  Oracle still provides [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-1360/6jalch346/index.html).  Earlier, they dropped OpenWindows in favor of CDE (see [transition guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-6331/index.html)).
- the escape sequences [manual](http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/5/dtterm/) for `dtterm` does not mention "mouse".

So: you should set `TERM` to `dtterm` if you are using that program.  vim will not know anything about its mouse capabilities.